# INFO Grub after use apt

Tags: apt, grub2, 20.04

after use apt for install, reinstall or remove any app.
appear in log one INFO creating a new entry in GRUB menu

[Like this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac8QC.png)

> INFO Requesting to save current system state
>
> INFO Updating GRUB menu

I no have idea if bad configured or this is correct

anywhare idea?

Answer (score 0):

discovered this is correct.
I`m used zsf. This is ZSYS he creates one snapshot for restoring the system when used the apt